# How to execute an ordered test list in VS2012 RC?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mstest

In VS2012 RC, I noticed that the test list editor, tests view and test lists are absent.

I have an ordered test list - how do I run this within VS2012?

Normally, I would go to the test view, select the ordered test list, and run it.

But without the test view, what do I do?

From the new Test Explorer window, all the tests appear in the 'Not Run' section. When I attempt to run the test associated with the ordered test list, I get this error:

> An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://orderedtestadapter/v1': Cannot find the test 'PhaseOneAdminLogonTest' with storage '..\bin\debug\codeduisanity.dll'.

Is there any way around this?

I was hoping to be able to start automating my tests using VS2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like when projects are upgraded from VS2010, the ordered test lists aren't upgraded too. I created a new ordered test list, and added the same items, then the tests worked.

Comment: Man, you saved my day! The problem is still there on GA version as well. I hit it in Load Tests. Load test mix was not upgraded, so I had to delete all tests from mix, add it back and it worked. Thanks!